# How can I input data into a mysql model from an array in GO?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

So, I'm working on this mysql model Using GO and GORM where the user can input their data

```
`package table

import (
    //"gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var Department = []string{"Computer Science", "Engineering", "Medical Science"}

type Account struct {
    gorm.Model
    Accountname  string `json:"name"`    //AccountName
    AccontNumber int64  ` json:"number"` //AccountNumber        Text(40)
   //need users to select one of the values from the Department Array
}`
```

I want my user to select a value from the ones **provided in the Department array** and store it in my table, how can I go about doing it?

Comment: you can try `gorm:"type:enum('published', 'pending', 'deleted');default:'pending'"`

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom string type for departments, but you still will have to explicitly check that the user provided string is correct:

```golang
type DepartmentName string

const (
    DepartmentComputerScience DepartmentName "Computer Science"
    DepartmentNameEngineering DepartmentName "Engineering"
    DepartmentNameMedicalScience DepartmentName "Medical Science"

)
var DepartmentsMap = map[DepartmentName]bool{
    DepartmentComputerScience: true, 
    DepartmentNameEngineering: true, 
    DepartmentNameMedicalScience: true,
}


type Account struct {
    gorm.Model
    Accountname  string         `json:"name"`    //AccountName
    AccontNumber int64          ` json:"number"` //AccountNumber        Text(40)
    Department   DepartmentName `json:"department"`
}

func (d DepartmentName) Valid() error {
    if _, ok := DepartmentsMap[d]; ok {
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("invalid department")
}
```

Comment: i made a syntax error, you should access the element from the map like ```DepartmentsMap[d]``` instead of the (). i edited my answer.